# Specialize generic function requirement on protocol inheritance

Tags: swift, generics

I have some protocol hierarchies on my code where I have protocols defining the objects I use and protocols defining functions to use with this objects.

The object protocols are inherited by other object protocols that add  more functionality to the original protocols and so are the functions that use them. The problem is that I can't find a way to specialize the function to take only the inherited parameter.

Here's some code to clarify what I'm trying to do:

```
protocol A {
    var foo: String { get set }
}
protocol B: A {
    var bar: String { get set }
}

struct Test: B {
    var foo: String = "foo"
    var bar: String = "bar"
}

protocol UseAProtocol {
    static func use<T: A>(_ obj: T)
}

protocol UseBProtocol: UseAProtocol {
}

extension UseBProtocol {
    //If I change the requirement to <T: B> this won't conform to `UseAProtocol`.
    static func use<T: A>(_ obj: T) {
        print(obj.foo)
        // print(obj.bar) - Since obj does not conform to `B` I can't access ".bar" here without a forced casting.
    }
}

struct Manager: UseBProtocol {
}

Manager.use(Test())
```

What I want to do is make the `use` function on the `UseBProtocol` only accept objects that conform to `B`. `B` inherits from `A`, but when I change from `<T:A>` to `<T:B>` I got an error saying that Manager does not conform to `UseAProtocol` and I have to change it back to `<T:A>`.

I know I can do this using `associatedtype` and `where` clauses on the inherit protocols - that's what I use today - but I wanted to move the generic requirement to the method so I could group all of them together under the same struct (I have a lot of this hierarchies and by using `associatedtype` I must use one struct by hierarchy). When the Conditional Conformances came to Swift this would be possible with `associatedtype`, but until them...

I could also use `as!` to force the casting from `A` to `B` on the `UseBProtocol` implementation, but that's a really bad solution and the error would be throw only at runtime.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Well I'm new to swift...but I can give you a pointer which can print both foo and bar...
extension UseBProtocol {
    static func use<T: A>(_ obj: T) {
        print(obj.foo)
    } static func use<T: B>(_ obj: T) {
        print(obj.foo) 
   print (obj.bar)  }
}

Comment: I don’t even know Swift, but I can tell you this is probably impossible using just the method signature. You’ve broken the Liskov Substitution Principle: a `UseBProtocol` should be valid wherever a `UseAProtocol` is valid, yet a `UseBProtocol` only works on `B`s where a `UseAProtocol` works on all `A`s. It will (probably) work if you flip the subtyping and make `UseAProtocol` a subtype of `UseBProtocol`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are actually looking for is an `associatedType` in `UseAProtocol` rather than making the `use` function generic.

By declaring an associated type in `UseAProtocol` and changing the function signature of `use` to `static func use(_ obj: ProtocolType)` your code compiles fine and you can access both `foo` and `bar` from `Manager`.

```
protocol AProtocol {
    var foo: String { get set }
}
protocol BProtocol: AProtocol {
    var bar: String { get set }
}

struct Test: BProtocol {
    var foo: String = "foo"
    var bar: String = "bar"
}

protocol UseAProtocol {
    associatedtype ProtocolType
    static func use(_ obj: ProtocolType)
}

protocol UseBProtocol: UseAProtocol {
}

extension UseBProtocol {
    static func use(_ obj: BProtocol) {
        print(obj.foo)
        print(obj.bar)
    }
}

struct Manager: UseBProtocol {
}

Manager.use(Test()) //prints both "foo" and "bar"
```

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for, but if I try to add a constraint to the associatedtype making it conform to 'A' or 'B' it would not conform.

I added the generic requirement because I want the UseAProtocol to use only AProtocol objects and the UseBProtocol to use only BProtocol (which are also AProtocol) objects.

Today I use associatedType with constraints like this on my code, but since it's a `class` requirement I need to use one struct for this 'A: B' example and another separate class for a alike hierarchy 'C: D' and another for a 'E: F'...